# Nginx Returning 404 with Static Files in Subfolder

Tags: laravel, nginx

I'm installing a Laravel app in a subfolder and only static files (JS/CSS) are returning 404.

I think the php location block needs something extra, but not sure.

Anyone else run into this or can provide some suggestions in fixing static files to serve properly?

```
location /laravel {
    alias /var/www/laravel/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @app;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
location @app {
    rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting and reading nginx docs, it was a quick fix.

I needed to add `^~` to let nginx know it can "stop searching" against other `location` blocks.

```
location ^~ /laravel {
    alias /var/www/laravel/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @app;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
location @app {
    rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

I hope this helps someone else, as it took me days (literally) to figure out.

Also, make sure your `fastcgi_params` has this below and not one of the different variations you'll find on the web:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
```